# How to achieve CI using Jenkins for multiple maven projects placed in bitbucket repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket, nexus

New to Jenkins and bitbucket..

We have several independent maven projects (microservices project with its own pom file) maintained under one repository in git bitbucket. We are trying to automate deployment process using Jenkins.
As of now, using online tutorials,  we have created a Jenkins maven job which is able to pull one maven project from bitbucket git, build and deploy the code to our server. 
Is there a way to configure Jenkins job to scan through the bitbucket repository and pull project/projects which was updated recently and then build them and deploy it to server? Is this achievable through single job using any dynamic parameters? Or do we need to configure one job for each project?

Appreciate your help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way to configure Jenkins job to scan through the bitbucket repository and pull project/projects which was updated recently and then build them and deploy it to server?*

Yes, you can setup webhook triggers in Bitbucket per repository to invoke your Jenkins pipelines using Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger plugin. More information about the plugin can be found here - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Or to start with you could use Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin or Git Plugin. More info here https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/121274372/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket

However, please note webhook trigger works at a repository level and NOT branch level. To make it work for specific branches only I'd suggest to read/ process the incoming webhook from Bitbucket and only trigger pipeline for ex if the webhook is coming from master or hotfix branch etc. This is achievable through Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger plugin

*Is this achievable through single job using any dynamic parameters?*

Yes, you can use a single pipeline to act as a webhook processor and read the incoming webhook coming from any repository and trigger the appropriate pipeline using dynamic variables. For ex. you can set the pipeline name format to be build_{repo_name}_{branch_name}. You can plug in the repo name and branch name values from the incoming webhook.

*Or do we need to configure one job for each project?*

It's your preference really :) I'd recommend playing with different options and go with what suits your requirements.